# After a long wait, the PAM window turns on asking for a password that never matches

Tags: pam, xscreensaver

After a long wait, the PAM window turns on asking for a password that never matches. It says:  
`xscreensaver: assuming NULL password means cancel`

and  
`xscreensaver: authentification via PAM cancelled`.  
The only way to solve the situation I know is to reboot or type sudo startx but it closes all previous application.
I use Lubuntu 20.04.
In auth.log is written: 
`xscreensaver[1976]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=  user=therion`  
and  
 `xscreensaver[1976]: FAILED LOGIN 3 ON DISPLAY ":0", FOR "therion" ack: private: Permission denied`.

Comment: Hello and welcome - can you describe *"the PAM window"* in more detail? Does it mention a specific PAM module, or anything else that could give us a clue what's happening? If so, please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: PAM is Pluggable Authentication Modules. After period of waiting of laptop the dialog appears demanding the password. I dont know the password it needs.

Comment: It wants the login password for the user whose session is locked.

Comment: The password I enter does not match. I have to enter virtual console.

Comment: You could turn off screen locking in the xscreensaver settings.

Comment: I turned of locking but what was the problem?